# Calling the face and emotion API at the same time

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

My goal is to take the live camera sample and create an app that uses the emotion api and the face api at the same time. Whenever it detects a face it should say Gender , Age , Emotion , Emotion detection confidance in a one string. 
I am having trouble with that because all of the function are async aurrnd it does frame analysis (analysis function) individually.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from Cognitive Services - Face API dev team, we are going to support emotion analyze during detection (in next release which should happen before April). It invoke the same interface provided by emotion API. So just be a little more patient and feel free to reach us if you have any further questions.

Bests,
Xuan (Sean) Hu.

Comment: Thank you, so what you are saying that soon the face API will be somewhat combined with the emotion API such that it will be fairly easy to create an app that finds: Gender, Age and Emotion at the same time ? Because that is exactly what I am trying to develop, thanks.

Comment: Yep, we are also working on other attributes, but sorry there is no promise currently. You may refer to the pull request of SDK sample which is not merged yet. e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/pull/7

Comment: Hi Xuan. Any updates rearding the release ? I remember you've said that It should happen before April. The reason I am asking is because I have a client that is waiting for an app that shoulld use Emotion and Face API calls at the same time so I am just trying to give him some answers for when I could make this for him :) Thanks !

Comment: Hi @NotSure, Here comes the Release Notes! Feel free to enjoy the new feature and any comments or suggestions are welcome! https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/ReleaseNotes#release-changes-in-march-2017

Comment: Thank you Xuan, one question. does the new Emotion attribute is the smile attribute ? Because I can see: Age, Gender, HeadPose,Smile,Glasses,FacialHair but no emotion. Just want to make sure.

Comment: Hi @NotSure, it is a new attribute, `smile` is kept just for back compatibility. You need to specify `emotion` in `returnFaceAttributes` in the request to get the corresponding result. Please have a look at the `Face - Detect` API reference for more details: https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

Comment: Hi Xuan, sorry for asking so many questions, I just want to get this done :) as you've said, it is a new attribute, and in face Detect Api reference it clearly explains all the attributes, Age,Gender,Smile,Headpose,glasses and emotion. But I see all the attributes except the latter. I made a list of the attributes I want and am using returnFaceAttrivutes with this list. Please have a look at a screen shot : https://ibb.co/iCdrva. What can I do ? Thanks again

Comment: Hi @NotSure, you need to update the Face SDK package. There are some latency cause we need some process like certificate sign off. Sorry for the inconvenience caused by that. Version 1.2.5 should works for you (which is deployed two days ago.)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried calling the same API via classes about frame analysis try checking [How to Analyze Videos in Real-time](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api/documentation/vision-api-how-to-topics/HowtoAnazlyzeVideo_Vision)

Comment: I've seen this guide but I know that the sample Microsoft is providing is using the Producer - Cunsumer approch. I'll try looking at it again.There must be a better approch than multithreading for this.