# Is it possible to call 2 API's and displaying a combined answer string at the same time?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am having trouble doing just that because of the await and async functions.
I want to have an app that analize a face in real time and is displaing the rectangle on his face and above it should say gender, age, emotion, emotion confidance. 
So I want to use the Face API and Emotion API at the same time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate with [Calling the face and emotion API at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590351/calling-the-face-and-emotion-api-at-the-same-time/42661730).

Please refer to that thread for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the C# SDKs, you can wait for both tasks to complete.  The code would like something like this:

```cs
static bool SameFace(Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.Contract.FaceRectangle r1,
        Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.Rectangle r2)
{
    // Fuzzy match of rectangles...
    return Math.Abs((r1.Top + r1.Height / 2) - (r2.Top + r2.Height / 2)) < 3 && 
        Math.Abs((r1.Left + r1.Width / 2) - (r2.Left + r2.Width / 2)) < 3;
}

void Test(string imageUrl)
{
    var faceClient = new FaceServiceClient(FACE_API_KEY);
    var emotionClient = new EmotionServiceClient(EMOTION_API_KEY);

    var faceTask = faceClient.DetectAsync(imageUrl, false, false, new FaceAttributeType[] { FaceAttributeType.Age, FaceAttributeType.Gender });
    var emotionTask = emotionClient.RecognizeAsync(imageUrl);

    Task.WaitAll(faceTask, emotionTask);

    var people = from face in faceTask.Result
                 from emotion in emotionTask.Result
                 where SameFace(face.FaceRectangle, emotion.FaceRectangle)
                 select new {
                     face.FaceAttributes.Gender,
                     face.FaceAttributes.Age,
                     emotion.Scores
                 };

    // Do something with 'people'
}
```

The tricky part is that the two APIs don't have the same rectangle type, and give slightly different values, hence a fuzzy match.